# Why does "block_given?" return false in debugger? (Works correctly when not debugging)

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug, pry

On testing with ruby debugger **block_given?** gives **false** but still executes, can someone explain me how its executed?.It is anything related to [context](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given?)(Is debugger changing context)?
if yes then how to find current context.

Now instead of **ruby-debug** when used **pry**  then **block_given?** returns **true**.

```
def test
  debugger
  if block_given?
    yield(4)
  else
    puts "ss"
  end
end
test {|el| puts "#{el}" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks  like a bug in ruby-debug, specifically [Kernel#binding_n](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#binding_005fn) which is what is getting used by the debugger.

You don't need to go into the debugger read/eval/print loop to see the bug. Here is a non-interactive example example replacing the *debugger()* call with *binding_n(0)*:

```
require 'rubygems'; require 'ruby-debug'
Debugger.start
def test
  puts eval("block_given?", binding_n(0))
  if block_given?
    yield(4)
  else
    puts "ss"
 end
end
test {|el| puts "#{el}" }
```

Pry doesn't have this problem probably because it uses Ruby's *binding()* rather than *binding_n()*. Of course that is the most reliable.

In the case above this is clearly a win here since *binding()* is what is exactly wanted. But as awesome as Pry is, it can't evaluate expressions in any stack frame context except the current (or most recent) stack frame.

See also http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/#comment-274 for differences between Pry and a debugger such as ruby-debug.

Lastly, I'll note that I tried this both in the patched MRI [1.9.2 trepanning debugger](https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki) as well as [rbx-trepanning for Rubinius](https://github.com/rocky/rbx-trepanning/wiki) 1.2-ish.

Both of them work as expected. In both, the equivalent of *binding_n* is done differently with more help from the Ruby runtime. That leaves [rb8-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rb8-trepanning) which has the bug because it uses *binding_n* as well.

Comment: Thanks, for inculcating on putting such point forward .I was skeptical of binding could be the cause of the issue but never dig such deep  Thanks Dude

Comment: @rocky, a recently released plugin for pry can let you walk the stack in a Pry session: https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer